# gsoap undefined reference in linux qt

Tags: c++, linux, qt, service, gsoap

I am trying to compile and run my first gsoap.. However in my main() I am getting `undefined reference to` error. I search on web, lots of solutions are for Windows.. I am programming in Linux(CentOS) and using Qt..

My .pro file is :

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.cpp \
    stdsoap2.cpp \
    soapC.cpp \
    soapClient.cpp

HEADERS += \
    stdsoap2.h \
    soapStub.h \
    soapH.h \
    soapCountryInfoServiceSoapBindingProxy.h
```

I didnt give link to `libgsoap++.a` because I already include `stdsoap2` in my project.

Error message is :

```
/.1/Projects/calisma/soapCountries/main.cpp:47: error: undefined reference to `__ns1__ListOfLanguagesByCode(soap*, _i__ListOfLanguagesByCode*, _i__ListOfLanguagesByCodeResponse*)'
:-1: error: collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here is my main.cpp and I am getting error in line `__ns1__ListOfLanguagesByCode(soap, code, result);`

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "CountryInfoServiceSoapBinding.nsmap"
#include "soapCountryInfoServiceSoapBindingProxy.h"

int main()
{
    CountryInfoServiceSoapBinding *countryObj;

    struct soap *soap = soap_new();

    countryObj = (CountryInfoServiceSoapBinding *)malloc(sizeof(CountryInfoServiceSoapBinding));

    if(countryObj == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Cannot allocate memory for countryobj";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    _i__ListOfLanguagesByCode *code;

    code = (_i__ListOfLanguagesByCode *)malloc(sizeof(_i__ListOfLanguagesByCode));

    if(code == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Cannot Allocate Memory for code";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    _i__ListOfLanguagesByCodeResponse *result;

    result = (_i__ListOfLanguagesByCodeResponse *)malloc(sizeof(_i__ListOfLanguagesByCodeResponse));

    if(result == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Cannot Allocate Memory for result";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    code = (_i__ListOfLanguagesByCode *)("tur");

    __ns1__ListOfLanguagesByCode(soap, code, result);

    std::cout << "result = " << result << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I couldnt figure out where is my error, or which part I am missing.. Basically I want to give code (which is "tur" in my example) and see the result of service.

Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT: Here is list of all cpp and .h file in project..

```
mg@mg-CentOS soapCountries]$ ll
total 1408
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mg papilon    560 May 22 10:04 CountryInfoServiceSoapBinding.nsmap
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mg papilon   1220 May 22 13:00 main.cpp
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mg papilon   1135 May 22 13:21 main.cpp.autosave
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mg papilon 707557 May 22 10:04 soapC.cpp
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mg papilon  48024 May 22 10:04 soapClient.cpp
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mg papilon    373 May 22 10:04 soapClientLib.cpp
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mg papilon    252 May 22 12:58 soapCountries.pro
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mg papilon  17907 May 22 15:02 soapCountries.pro.user
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mg papilon   7148 May 22 12:01 soapCountryInfoServiceSoapBindingProxy.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mg papilon 151092 May 22 10:04 soapH.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mg papilon  39137 May 22 10:04 soapServer.cpp
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mg papilon    373 May 22 10:04 soapServerLib.cpp
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mg papilon  49034 May 22 10:04 soapStub.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 mg papilon 311882 Jun  6  2004 stdsoap2.cpp
-rw-r--r-- 1 mg papilon  56325 Jun  6  2004 stdsoap2.h
```

EDIT 2:

Definition of int `__ns1__ListOfLanguagesByCode` which is located inside `"soapCountryInfoServiceSoapBindingProxy.h"`

```
virtual int __ns1__ListOfLanguagesByCode(_i__ListOfLanguagesByCode *i__ListOfLanguagesByCode, _i__ListOfLanguagesByCodeResponse *i__ListOfLanguagesByCodeResponse) { return soap ? soap_call___ns1__ListOfLanguagesByCode(soap, endpoint, NULL, i__ListOfLanguagesByCode, i__ListOfLanguagesByCodeResponse) : SOAP_EOM; }
```

Comment: Did you add all files generated by gsoap? I think it generates more files (cpp file for bindingproxy for example). Also find in what cpp file __ns1__ListOfLanguagesByCode function is defined

Comment: @demonplus please see edit.. I wrote all cpp and .h file which are included in project

Comment: could you find __ns1__ListOfLanguagesByCode function in any of these cpp files?

Comment: @demonplus yes it is inside soapCountryInfoServiceSoapBindingProxy.h.. Please see EDIT2 for definiton

Comment: @demonplus yes, I found it is inside soapC.cpp which is generated and also included in my project

Comment: I also mentioned that in implementation it has two arguments and you are calling it with additional soap (first) argument, try to remove it

Comment: it is my bad.. first I was calling this function with CountryInfo object, however created empty soap, then I am creating soap and calling another  function which has 3 parameters soap, code, result..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78526/discussion-between-demonplus-and-gogud).

Comment: Here is function type in soapC.cpp: `SOAP_FMAC3 struct __ns1__ListOfLanguagesByCode * SOAP_FMAC4 soap_get___ns1__ListOfLanguagesByCode(struct soap*, struct __ns1__ListOfLanguagesByCode *, const char*, const char*);`

Comment: So is it possible to call __ns1__ListOfLanguagesByCode with two arguments or soap_in___ns1__ListOfLanguagesByCode with 4 arguments?

Comment: did you find any answer to this question?

Answer (score 0):

I think in your .pro file need add next the string:
LIBS += -lgsoap

Comment: I think that lgsoap library for windows. But as I told you I am using linux. In my gsoap folder I have libgsoap++.a (I think that is same as lgsoap in windows ).. However adding this library in .pro file didnt change anything. Also as I understand from gsoap manuel book, I dont need to include this library because I already add stdsoap2.cpp and .h files in my project.

Comment: on Windows you never include gsoap, too. The gsoap is used only to generate files and then files are included

Comment: can try  #locate libgsoap++.a  or #locate stdsoap2.a  and add this path to  your PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH  ?